# Solving an equation involving a trace: find $X$ in $M=\mathrm{Tr}[CX]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

So, I have this algebra problem:

> I have an equation of the form $$M_{ij}=\sum_{A,B}C_{ij}^{AB} X^{AB}
>  \equiv \mathrm{Tr}\big[C_{ij}X\big]$$ where upper upper-case letters
>   are some kind of indices and lower lower-case ones are some others.
>   $M_{ij}$ and $C_{ij}^{AB}$ are known matrices of different types I have to solve this equation in order to find $X_{ij}$.

Well, despite it may looks like a simple linear system, it is not. I don't know how to invert it and find the $X$ matrix. Reasonably, I think it could always be solved if the dimensionality of $M$ equals that of $X$, that is, if I have enough equations for the independent variables of my problem. Is it true?

Can someone give me some tips or suggestions on how to work out this problem?

Thank you all in advance!

---

EDIT: probably, the $X$ matrix inside the trace should be transposed:$$M_{ij}=\mathrm{Tr}[C_{ij}X^T],$$but still.

Comment: Are $X^{AB}$ and $X$ related in some way or they are completely different objects?

Comment: Yes! $X^{AB}$ is the $(A,B)$ element, that is a number, of the $X$ matrix. You can see this element as the one in the $A$-th row and $B$-th column of $X$. The same relationship holds for the $M$ matrix and the $M_{ij}$ element. Anyway, $X$ and $M$ are different kind of matrices (in the same way as uppercase letter indices and lowercase letter ones) since they're defined in different spaces. $C_{ij}^{AB}$ is the $(i,j;A,B)$-element of a generalized matrix with two pairs of different indices...  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be easily transformed to a linear system via [vectorize the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29). Make use of isomorphism $\mathrm{vec}:\mathbb{R}^m\otimes\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, we can write $m=\mathrm{vec}~M, x=\mathrm{vec}~X$ as column vectors and $c$ as a matrix corresponding to $C$. Or $$m=cx$$
After obtaining the solution $x$ for the above equation, you can obtain $X$ by rearrangement of $x$.

Comment: Good answer, Shuchang! Thank you! Anyway, it still remains unclear to me how the $C$ matrix should transform through the vectorization. Should I vectorize *separately* on the two different pairs of indices? That is, I have to find a "true" matrix $C$ whose elements are of the form $C_\delta^\Gamma$ where Greek uppercase letters span (or cover) all the possible combinations of Latin uppercase letters, and the same for lewercase ones. In this case, the linear system has solution(s) $C^{-1}m=x$ if $C$ is an invertible matrix. Is it right? Thanks!

Comment: @AstoundingJB Exactly. Note originally $C$ is a linear mapping from $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^p\otimes\mathbb R^q$. And you need only to vectorize both domain and range to obtain the matrix $C^\Gamma_\delta$.

Comment: Well, I think that your answer is correct and completely solves my problem! Up voted and accepted! Thank you Shuchang!